# Using the result of the MATCH formula as a reference for a cell range?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet from which I need to get the row number of a cell wich matches a condition. For that I am using a formula like the following

```
=MATCH( ( if(LM!A:A,eomonth(LM!A:A,1)+1,) ),LM!A:A,2,0)
```

In that case the output is `29`

What I would like to do now is incorporate that output inside a bigger function using that `29` as the range for my condition. For example in the following formula

```
=FILTER( LM!B29:B363 ; ROW(LM!B29:B363) =MAX( FILTER( ROW(LM!B29:B363) ; NOT(ISBLANK(LM!B29:B363)))))-VLOOKUP( ( if(LM!A:A,eomonth(LM!A:A,1)+1,) ),LM!A:G,2,TRUE)
```

I would like to replace `B29` with `B` + `the value from the MATCH output`

How can I incorporate that into my formula?

Any tip will be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't cross post - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36137/how-can-i-reference-a-cell-from-the-result-of-a-match-function-in-google-spreads

Comment: Yes, my mistake, sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is to use [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs&tab=1240292). For example, if `some_expression` evaluates to 29, then `INDIRECT("LM!B"&some_expression&":B363")`will reference the range LM!B29:B363.

That being said, I think there must be a more straightforward way of doing what you require. Can you explain in words what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks!I will test it now.In words what I have is a table with a time series in sheet A and that `B29` manually refers to the first day of the current month in that time series data.I made the MATCH formula in order to automatically grab which row hold the first day of the current month, but I was not sure how to _call_ that value from my main formula. I am not sure that was clear, I hope it is, let me know if I can provide more info. I will be testing your code now, thanks!

Comment: Yes, but what do you want to do with that row? I mean, what is your entire use case? eg "I want to find the value in column X that corresponds with the first entry in the current month, and subtract that from the last value in column X"

Comment: Basically its simple, I need to have on Sheet B the following: Given the data on Sheet A (Timestamp, Aggregated amount) get the current balance for the current month. The issue I have is that the amount is not a daily amount, its the total balance, so I have to subtract the last value on Sheet A to the last value of the last day of the previous month to have the actual balance for the month. Can you think of another formula besides the one in my original question? Thanks A LOT!

Comment: `=FILTER(LM!B:B;LM!A:A=MAX(LM!A:A))-FILTER(LM!B:B;LM!A:A=MAX(FILTER(LM!A:A;LM!A:A<DATE(YEAR(GoogleClock());MONTH(GoogleClock());1))))`

Comment: Tested, works beautifully. Many thanks for all your time, help, and teach